# How to display readable date format from a timestamp in php

Tags: php

I have a timestamp like this `2017-10-01 21:33:37`

What I am trying to achieve is I want to display this as when it is parsed by PHP

Like: September 29, 2017

How to achieve so?

i am trying to do like this `<?php echo $value['created']; ?>`

i have tried using `strtotime` the `date` function but didn't get the output

Comment: What have you tried so far (where is the code)? See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: i have updated the question @Peter

Comment: Are you sure that `2017-10-01 21:33:37` is a timestamp, and not a string? Timestamps are integer numbers

Comment: no actually i have set this in mysql data by default curent_timestamp